# Angular NGRX multiple store

Tags: angular, ngrx

- Angular 10
- ngrx/store: 9.2.0

Hello, I have an app including multiple store, let give you an instance, I have User and Roles,
each user belong to a Role and each role has its own properties,

- User (id, fullname, role_id, status, ...)
- Role (id, name, resources, etc...)

I have fully NGRX setup for Role, CRUD operation are working fine, now it's time to start setup the store for User too, but User module is a bit different, for example in the data table of user I want to show the role's name and resources, now the question here is:

1. Shall I create special model for User, which is contains user columns as well as to extra cols role name and resources, or should I get the role info from server using user effect by passing role id to role service and update the state with role information ? if so would you please give me a hint ?
2. in NGRX the model should be as it is and the within the other components I can get the information of another store, for example User model as it is and doing it's own CRUD , as well as Role , and the in User data table component when I fetched the user info, pass the role id to Role action to get the role info? does the architecture should be like this or what ?

I am using lazy loading , and each module is inside it's own folder :

```
modules:
- user
-- components
-- store
--- user.model.ts
--- user.actions.ts
--- user.effects.ts
--- user.reducer.ts
--- user.selectors.ts
- user.module.ts
- user-routing.module.ts

- Role
-- components
-- store
--- role.model.ts
--- role.actions.ts
--- role.effects.ts
--- role.reducer.ts
--- role.selectors.ts
- role.module.ts
- role-routing.module.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Your store setup is fine in my eyes.
If you want to connect multiple slices of the store, selectors are the way to go.
See my blog post [Sharing data between modules is peanuts](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts) for more info and an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't have the root state, shall I create it ? if so it means next to app.component.ts I should create it ?

Comment: You should only put things in the root state when that state must be accessed in multiple feature modules. We have `authentication` or `master config` state in the rootstore as an example

Comment: thanks, in my scenario which i have to independent module like user and role and they have their own state, should i add role state to root state in order to use it in user state or what ?

Comment: To be honst, I don't know. It all depends on the use case. If it makes things easier, sure why not.